# How to add a column of checkbox in a grid where only one can be selected across all rows?

Tags: java, checkbox, gwt, radio-button, gxt

I have an Inline Editable grid with a column for checkboxes. How do I make sure that only one of those checkboxes in all the rows is checked? Whenever the user checks one checkbox, the previously selected checkbox if any should get unselected by default.

Comment: Your case need radio button not check boxes

Comment: I have tried to add radio Buttons of the same group in columns. It doesn't work.

Comment: Don't waste your time and write more usefulness code in checkbox, try to make radio button working, and you can your radio button code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about Sencha GXT, the following code will work:

Create a IdentifyValueProvider and a SelectionModel:

```
IdentityValueProvider<M> identity = new IdentityValueProvider<M>();
final CheckBoxSelectionModel<M> selectionModel = new CheckBoxSelectionModel<M>(identity);
```

Add the checkbox column to your grid with:

```
columns.add(selectionModel.getColumn());
```

And add the SelectionModel to the grid:

```
grid.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
```

Setting the selection mode to SINGLE will solve your requirement:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
```

Hope that helps.